# Simple bash syntax failing passwd

Tags: bash, scripting

Whenever I try to enter the password for a new user through pipe it doesn't work for me.. this is the command:

```
echo "${PASSWORD}" | passwd ${USER_NAME}
```

However it fails to work, what am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`passwd` doesn't support reading password from stdin in this fashion. Furthermore, it prompts for old password (if ran as user) and twice for new password. This can of course be [scripted using expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433557/11529761).

Comment: There isn't any additional way? I'm not really familliar with the except syntax.
I've seen someone typing 
--stdin with the passwd, however it doesn't work for me.. maybe not supported anymore I don't know.

Comment: The linked answer on SO contains more or less the complete script, so it should be possible to modify to your usecase.